# How do I fix a javascript file not found error on Windows 10 while I am certain it works on Manjaro Linux?

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, tailwind-css, manjaro

## Windows 10 vs Manjaro Linux serving Javascript

So this is brain breaker. I have a `Django` web application that makes use of `TailwindCss`. On a certain page I have made use of a `TailwindCss` plugin named [TW-Elements](https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/getting-started/quick-start/). This plugin allows me to easily implement [tab functionality](https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/navigation/tabs/).

However, when I run the code on my `Manjaro Linux` operating system it works like a charm. When running the same code on a `Windows` operating system (not my choice) I get the following error:

[image]

The workaround is running everything from a `Docker` container and not be dependent on `Windows`. Although this works my brain needs to know WHY this problem occurs in the first place. It is probably something super simple and annoying from the `Javascript` world. Please help me uncovering this mystery.

## Here are some extra details

I used `pnpm` to install the `package.json` node modules in a folder called `jstoolchain`. This folder also holds the `package.json`.

Below is the html template I use the following code to retrieve the `Javascript` module:

```html
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="/jstoolchain/node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js">
    </script>
```

Below is the `package.json` file. Please note I use a different `Django` tree structure. `APP_FOLDER` holds all the apps and `theme` all the templates and static resources.

```json
{
  "name": "jstoolchain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "../../static/js/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tailwind-watch": "tailwindcss -i ../APP_FOLDER/theme/static/css/input.css -o ../static/css/output.css --watch",
    "tailwind-build": "tailwindcss -i ../APP_FOLDER/theme/static/css/input.css -o ../static/css/output.css --minify"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "idb": "^7.1.1",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Below is the `tailwind.config.js` file also located in `jstoolchain`:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "../dcc_facilitator/theme/templates/**/*.{html,js}",
        "../dcc_facilitator/**/templates/**/*.{html,js}",
        "venv/Lib/site-packages/crispy_tailwind/**/*.html",
        "venv/Lib/site-packages/crispy_tailwind/**/*.py",
        "venv/Lib/site-packages/crispy_tailwind/**/*.js",
        "./jstoolchain/node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js",
    ],
    plugins: [
        require("tw-elements/dist/plugin"),
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    ],
    darkMode: "class",
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Open Sans', /*...*/ defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I tried different node modules installations with different versions of `node js` and `pnpm` operating systems (Windows and Linux).

WINDOWS 10:

- node version: v20.11.0 | v21.6.1 (tried both)
- pnpm: 8.14.3

MANJARO LINUX:

- node version: v21.5.0
- pnpm: 8.13.1

Comment: Maybe it's a browser issue. Try a different browser on Windows. Try incognito window. Try running the webserver on Windows and the browser on Linux.

Comment: Your webserver (Django? Node.js?) reports a HTTP 404 (not found) error for one of the .js files: tw-elements.umd.min.js. As a quick workaround, copy the file from the Linux machine to the Windows machine.

Comment: So I have a different project, same setup. Same modules and here it works. So I tried copying the complete `node_modules` folder over. The problem persists. This got me indeed believing it might be an browser issue somehow.

Comment: Additional info, I tried it on the Manjaro Linux with the different projects. One works, one not. So it does not seem to be an operating system issue.

Comment: Following seems to resolve it:

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"></script>